# Minimize JQuery Dialogextend with a button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have this jqueryui dialogextend dialog box implemented. I want this to be able to minimize when I click anywhere in the body as I am using this dialog box to upload some files and the main page user is allowed to input some data. So my question is how to minimize the dialogextend dialog box whenever the user click on the parent page (as for now it works when the user click on the minimize button).

here is my jqueryui dialogextend dialog box

```
$(".myClass").click(function () {
    $("#somediv").dialog({
        width: 400,
        height: 450
    }).dialogExtend({
         "closable": true,
         "maximizable": false,
         "minimizable": true,
         "collapsable": false,
    });
    return false;
    });
```

this is how it looks

[image]

So when the user click on anywhere in the parent page i want the dialog box to minimize. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So then after long hours of many failed attempts I managed to found few ways of doing this.

First method is you add an $(document).On method to add a click event to the main div which allows you to track any click on the page and hide the dialogbox if it is shown

The aforementioned method works but I think the better solution would be to override the existing functionality of the minimize and close buttons of the jquery dialogextend so one can hide and show the dialogbox on clicking on a button and can use the docking function like behaviour as well if the dialogboxextend events are overwritten.

this is how i did that if anyone need to do it in the future.

First I will create the jqueryui dialogboxextend dialog box

```
            $(".myCusClass").click(function () { 
            $("#divDialog").dialog({
                width: 400,
                height: 450
            }).dialogExtend({
                "closable": true,
                "maximizable": false,
                "minimizable": true,
                "restore": false,
                "collapsable": false,
                beforeMinimize: function (event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#divDialog").hide();
                    $("#minimizedDiv").show();
                    $("#divDialog").close();
                },
                beforeRestore: function (event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#divDialog").hide();
                    $("#minimizedDiv").hide();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

notice that I have override the beforeminimize and beforerestore method so I can hide and show the dialog box without actually closing the dialog. the following explains about the docker.

```
<div id="minimizedDiv" class="panel  panel-default " style="width: 200px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: -20px; display: none;">
   <div class="panel-heading top-bar ">
      <span class="ui-dialog-title" style="width: 150px; margin-left: -5px"><b style="vertical-align: top;">Attach files...</b>
      </span>
      <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-plus ui-corner-all ui-state-default" href="#" title="maximize" role="button" onclick="RestoreWindow()"></a>
      <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all ui-state-default" href="#" title="close" role="button" onclick="CloseWindow()"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

The above will act as the docker which will be used when dialogbox is minimized. following are the functions used to restore and close the dialog box from the docker

```
function RestoreWindow() {
        $("#divDialog").show();
        $("#minimizedDiv").hide();
    }

function CloseWindow() {
        $('#divDialog').dialog('close'); 
    }
```